# Serializing output to JSON - ValueError: Circular reference detected

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm trying to output results of my mysql query to JSON. 
I have problem with serializing datetime.datetime field, so I wrote small function to do that:

```
def date_handler(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'):
        return obj.isoformat()
    else:
        return obj
```

and then in main code I'm just running:

```
products_json = []
for code in best_matching_codes:
    cur = db.cursor()
    query = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE code LIKE '%s'" % (PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME, product_code)
    cur.execute(query)
    columns = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        products_json.append(dict((k,v) for k,v in zip(columns,row)))   

return json.dumps(products_json, default = date_handler)
```

However, since I wrote date_handler function, I'm getting "ValueError: Circular reference detected"

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2013 00:42:18] "GET /1/product?code=9571%2F702 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/pisarzp/Desktop/SusyChoosy/susyAPI/test1.py", line 69, in product_search
return json.dumps(products_json, default = date_handler)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
**kw).encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
ValueError: Circular reference detected
```

What did I break? Is there a better way to serialize output to JSON?

Comment: Could you get the print output for products_json? I guess there are some duplicated between the key with value on date. Then it can get the similar error.

Answer (score 28):

The function you pass as the `default` argument will only be called for objects that are not natively serializable by the `json` module. It must return a serializable object, or raise a TypeError.

Your version returns the same object you were passed if it's not of the one type you're fixing (dates). That is causing the circular reference error (which is misleading, since the circle is between one object and itself after being processed by `date_handler`).

You can start to fix this by changing `date_handler` to raise an exception in its `else` block. That will still probably fail, but you can probably then find out what object it is that is in your data structure causing the problem using code like this:

```
def date_handler(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'):
        return obj.isoformat()
    else:
        raise TypeError(
            "Unserializable object {} of type {}".format(obj, type(obj))
        )
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of raising the `TypeError` yourself, you should relay the call to `JSONEncoder`'s default-method:

```
def date_handler(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'):
        return obj.isoformat()
    else:
        json.JSONEncoder.default(self,obj)
```

This will also raise `TypeError` and is a better practice, it allows for `JSONEncoder` to try and encode the type your method can't.

Comment: I got `NameError: global name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: Just try returning str(obj)

Comment: i have face same problem with array list inside json and change variable name then got error is gone

Comment: you would want to return your result in your else branch

Answer (score 2):

```
json.dumps(obj, default=method_name)
```

> "method_name" function must be return a serialize object.

```
def method_name(obj):
    data = {
            '__class__': obj.__class__.__name__,
            '__module__': obj.__module__
           }
    data.update(obj.__dict__)
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of raising an error you could simply [Remove circular references in dicts, lists, tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777369/remove-circular-references-in-dicts-lists-tuples), making the object serializable